# flash player 10.2: fullscreen on 2 monitors

Tags: flash, flashplayer-10

according to release notes in flashplayer 10.2 you can do fullscreen on multiple monitors.

how can i trigger this behaviour?

and is it user configurable?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Adobe Flash Player Team Blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/02/flash-player-10-2-launch.html) : With ***multiple display full screen support*** in Flash Player 10.2, you can now easily watch your favorite videos  in true full screen on one display while you multitask on another.

As in the previous version of Flash Player, you need a [hack](http://lifehacker.com/#!5419028/keep-flash-videos-in-full-screen-on-dual-monitors) to do so. So I don't think it's something for the user to configure.